# Error adding GameObject to list in class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, object-pooling

I am having issues in adding a `GameObject` to a `List<>`. When I build this program an error occurs in `poolInstances.Add(clone)`:

> Error: List.Add(RecyclingGameObject) has some
>   invalid arguments.

Error also occur on `return clone;` line:

> Error: Cannot implicitly convert Gameobject to RecyclingGameObject

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections; 
using System.Collections.Generic;  
public class ObjectPool : MonoBehaviour { 

public RecyclingGameObjects prefabs;    

    private List<RecyclingGameObjects> poolInstances = new List<RecyclingGameObjects();  

    private RecyclingGameObjects createInstance(Vector3 pos){   
        var clone = GameObject.Instantiate (prefabs) as GameObject  ;       
        clone.transform.position = pos;         
        clone.transform.parent = transform;  

        poolInstances.Add (clone);      

        return clone; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
var clone = GameObject.Instantiate (prefabs) as GameObject  ;
```

with

```
var clone = GameObject.Instantiate (prefabs) as RecyclingGameObjects;
```

Because you declared the list as `RecyclingGameObjects`, with  `List<RecyclingGameObjects> poolInstances`, the object type to add to the list must be type of `RecyclingGameObjects` object not GameObject.